# Collection return type of OperationContract and how to add to a list of DataContracts?

Tags: c#, wcf, list, datacontract, operationcontract

I have a Business Domain Object (**BDO**) class:

```
public class BDO_LIST_DEPARTMENTS
{
    public int DEPARTMENT_ID { get; set; }
    public string DEPARTMENT_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a `DataContract` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS
{
    [DataMember]
    public int DEPARTMENT_ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string DEPARTMENT_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

And in my service layer, I have tried to convert the **BDO** into a `DataContract` and then return a List of this `DataContract`, being the return type of the `OperationContract`:

```
[OperationContract]
    IList<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> GetAllDepartments();
```

Here was my original attempt in my service layer:

```
public IList<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS DCDepartment = new DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS();
        IList<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> DCListOfDepartments = new List<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS>();
        ICollection<BDO_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> BDOListOfDepartments = Bal.GetAllDepartments();

        foreach (BDO_LIST_DEPARTMENTS BDODepartment in BDOListOfDepartments)
        {
              DCDepartment.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDODepartment.DEPARTMENT_ID;
              DCDepartment.DEPARTMENT_NAME = BDODepartment.DEPARTMENT_NAME;
              DCListOfDepartments.Add(DCDepartment);
        }

        return DCListOfDepartments;
    }
```

As you can see, I have attempted to add a single `DataContract` to a `IList<DataContract>`, but when I do so, it changes every other item of that list into the same `DataContract` with the same details.

**Therefore, my question is, what is the correct return type for an `OperationContract`, how do I return a list of a `DataContract` class and how do I add to that list without changing the data of all other items in the list?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a collection data contract

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS_LIST : List<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> {
  ...
}
```

and use this collection data contract as return type of operation method.

```
public DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS_LIST  GetAllDepartments() {
   ...
}
```

and here is the modified implementation for service method:

```
public DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS_LIST   GetAllDepartments() {

            IList<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> DCListOfDepartments = new List<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS>();
            ICollection<BDO_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> BDOListOfDepartments = Bal.GetAllDepartments();

            foreach (BDO_LIST_DEPARTMENTS BDODepartment in BDOListOfDepartments) {
                DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS DCDepartment = new DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS() {
                    DEPARTMENT_ID = BDODepartment.DEPARTMENT_ID,
                    DEPARTMENT_NAME = BDODepartment.DEPARTMENT_NAME
                };
                DCListOfDepartments.Add(DCDepartment);
            }

            return DCListOfDepartments;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I created a CollectionDataContract which inherits the IList, what would I put inside of the class as the property? And when I add to that class, will it not just produce the same outcome?

Comment: the problem in your method 'GetAllDepartments()' is that the same department object is added into the list several times. And all the dc department object equals the same with last BDO list object.

Comment: Alright, thank you, could you please provide an example of what goes into the CollectionDataContract class as the property, as it is asking for an implementation of an interface member 'IList<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS>.IndexOf(DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS)'?

Comment: changing class DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS_LIST  to be derived from List<DC_LIST_DEPARTMENTS> will avoid implementing all the interface methods. answer updated.